# check if client press on option tag

Tags: php

I need to check if isset $_POST of 'option' tag.

For example, to know when the client pressed on 'select' tag i'm doing this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['select_tag'])) {
    echo 'the client pressed on the select tag';
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <select name="select_tag">
        <option value="1">1st</option>
        <option value="2">2nd</option>
        <option value="3">3rd</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I need to know if the client press on value 1, 2 or 3, there is a way to check it?

Comment: You know if statements but you don't know about the `==` operator? Please do yourself (and everyone else who has to deal with your code) a favor and find more tutorials about programming before you continue.

Comment: @Terminus people like you don't useful in this site, if you want to help your welcome and if not you can skip to the next question that you think in your mind as "good question to ask", have a good day

Comment: Ignore how I said it for a minute and consider going through some tutorials (on programming in general or on php specifically) you will not regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$_POST['select_tag']` itself you will get selected value from selectbox

```
if (isset($_POST['select_tag'])) {
    echo 'the client pressed on the select tag '.$_POST['select_tag'];
}
```

Output:

```
the client pressed on the select tag 1.
```